# Is there any tool or add on or anything by which i can know how many times I have opened a website in a browser?

Tags: browsers, tools, application

Is there any tool or add on or anything by which i can know how many times I have opened a website in a browser?

I use google chrome. I want to know "whether I have visited a particular website before or not"

Answer (score 2):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jificbcgkgbgddjehcegimolpobpcpbl